# Idempotence of to_euler() and to_matrix()

Tags: python

I expected

```
Euler((a, b, c), 'XYZ').to_matrix().to_euler('XYZ') == Euler((a, b, c), 'XYZ')
```

However at least for

```
a = radians(30) 
b = radians(90)
c = radians(45)
```

This is not the cases since the left hand side evaluates to:

```
Euler((-0.2617993950843811, 1.570796251296997, 0.0), 'XYZ')
```

and the right hand side to:

```
Euler((0.5235987901687622, 1.5707963705062866, 0.7853981852531433), 'XYZ')
```

Why is this the case, am I understanding the functions or wrong? Do I misunderstand the concept of Euler angles?

Comment: [Related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock#Loss_of_a_degree_of_freedom_with_Euler_angles)  Different Eulers can have equivalent result rotation.  Will (i believe) work as expected with quaternions.

Comment: Look into what is called a *Gimbal Lock*. `b = radians(90)` is a textbook example of this. If you want to avoid this, it's better to use quaternions.

Comment: Snap: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny the link posted in comment above is the _Gimbal Lock_ wiki page, anchored at text book example of b = pi / 2.

Comment: Thanks! I'll switch to quaterions. @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny if you'll post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @batFINGER yeah I didn't click the link, thought 'related' linked to another similar question like cegaton usually links so I didn't bother:)